# Why are there gaps inbetween cells?

Tags: javascript, rendering, raycasting

I'm in the process of creating a raycast engine in pure JavaScript, and I just implemented the DDA algorithm for optimization. However, there's an issue with the rendering where there are gaps between each box: [image: rendering issue]

The DDA algorithm is meant to jump automatically to the next point at which it will hit one of the boxes that make up the map. This is the function that implements that for each ray:

```
function getDistances() {
    for (var i = 0; i < Game.rays.quantity; i++) {
      // get current angle of the ray
      var angle = Game.toRad((Game.player.angle - (Game.rays.fov / 2)) + ((Game.rays.fov / Game.rays.quantity) * i));
      var rayX = Game.player.x;
      var rayY = Game.player.y;
      // pre-calculate sin, cos, and tan for angle
      var sin = Math.sin(angle);
      var cos = Math.cos(angle);
      var tan = Math.tan(angle);
      var hitWall = false;

      for (var j = 0; j < Game.rays.renderDistance; j++) {
        // get the closest X and Y coordinate for the ray
        var stepX, stepY;

        if (sin < 0) {
          stepY = (Math.floor((rayY - 1) / Game.mapConfig.blockSize) * Game.mapConfig.blockSize) - rayY;
        } else {
          stepY = (Math.ceil((rayY + 1) / Game.mapConfig.blockSize) * Game.mapConfig.blockSize) - rayY;
        }
        if (cos < 0) {
          stepX = (Math.floor((rayX - 1) / Game.mapConfig.blockSize) * Game.mapConfig.blockSize) - rayX
        } else {
          stepX = (Math.ceil((rayX + 1) / Game.mapConfig.blockSize) * Game.mapConfig.blockSize) - rayX;
        }
      

        // closest coordinate pairs where ray intersects a box (rounded to X and Y)
        var nearX = [rayX + stepX, (stepX * tan) + rayY]; // blue
        var nearY = [(stepY / tan) + rayX, rayY + stepY]; // purple

        // take the X and Y coordinates and get the box it hit from Game.map.data
        // this is where the issues are
        var mapX, mapY;

        if (Game.distanceTo([rayX, rayY], nearX) < Game.distanceTo([rayX, rayY], nearY)) {
          // hits side of box
          rayX = nearX[0];
          rayY = nearX[1];
          
          if (cos < 0) { // facing left
            mapX = Math.floor(rayX / Game.mapConfig.blockSize) - 1;
            mapY = Math.floor(rayY / Game.mapConfig.blockSize);
          } else { // facing right
            mapX = Math.floor(rayX / Game.mapConfig.blockSize);
            mapY = Math.floor(rayY / Game.mapConfig.blockSize);
          }
        } else {
          // hits top/bottom of box
          rayX = nearY[0];
          rayY = nearY[1];

          if (sin < 0) { // facing down
            mapX = Math.floor(rayX / Game.mapConfig.blockSize);
            mapY = Math.floor(rayY / Game.mapConfig.blockSize) - 1;
          } else { // facing up
            mapX = Math.floor(rayX / Game.mapConfig.blockSize);
            mapY = Math.floor(rayY / Game.mapConfig.blockSize);
          }
        }

        // check if the box is solid; if so, stop the ray
        if (Game.checkSolid(mapY, mapX)) {
          hitWall = true;
          var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(rayX - Game.player.x, 2) + Math.pow(rayY - Game.player.y, 2));
          Game.rays.distances[i] = [distance, Game.map.data[mapY][mapX]];
          break;
        }
      }

      if (!hitWall) {
        Game.rays.distances[i] = [Infinity, " "];
      }
    }
  }
```

It seems that whenever the ray encounters a box's corner, it skips through it when checking if the box is solid, because it's checking the wrong box. I think I'm calculating `mapX` and `mapY` incorrectly, but I'm not entirely sure.

The map is a set of nested arrays, so to access the top-left cell, you would need to call `Game.map.data[0][0]`.

Does anybody know what could be wrong here?

For those interested, the full code can be found here: [raycaster](https://github.com/TylerSelden/raycaster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing +1 and -1 values to smaller values seems like solves the problem. Please let me know if you need something else.

```
    if (sin < 0) {
      stepY = (Math.floor((rayY - 0.00000000001) / Game.mapConfig.blockSize) * Game.mapConfig.blockSize) - rayY;
    } else {
      stepY = (Math.ceil((rayY + 0.00000000001) / Game.mapConfig.blockSize) * Game.mapConfig.blockSize) - rayY;
    }
    if (cos < 0) {
      stepX = (Math.floor((rayX - 0.00000000001) / Game.mapConfig.blockSize) * Game.mapConfig.blockSize) - rayX
    } else {
      stepX = (Math.ceil((rayX + 0.00000000001) / Game.mapConfig.blockSize) * Game.mapConfig.blockSize) - rayX;
    }
```